# Why is my ActiveRecord updated_at timstamp column defaulting to negative Infinity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, timestamp, database-migration

I recently migrated my database from Postgres to MySQL, as well as upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 5.

The documentation says that the default for both `created_on` and `updated_on` columns should be the current time, when created.  For some reason, my `updated_on` column is now defaulting to `-Infinity` which is making some of my code freak out.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem was caused by the migration tool I used to migrate the MySQL database to Postgres, called [NMIG](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/nmig).  NMIG migrates not just the data, but the schema as well, and there's no way to stop it from overwriting the schema even if you already have one setup. Well, for whatever reason, the mapping it uses for the `updated_on` column (and presumably `updated_at` columns too?) defines the default as `-Infinity`!

In order to get around this, I created a fresh PG database by updating my database.yml with a new database name, running `db:create` and `db:schema:load` and then used [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html) to dump the postgres data, and `pg_restore -a` to restore just the data, without overwriting the schema.  Tada! :)